# Stuck at Collab RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu and cuda:

Tags: python, gpu, google-colaboratory

I checked and see that I have all define my tensor in GPU (the context_vector) , but when I run on Colab, it always display the error of "Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cpu and cuda"
The error track is like this:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-bf7edd8e474b> in <module>()
     85     for context, target in data:
     86         context_vector = make_context_vector(context)
---> 87         log_probs = model(context_vector)
     88         total_loss += loss_function(log_probs, torch.tensor([target]).to(device))
     89     #optimize at the end of each epoch
```

Here is my make_context_vector function :

```
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')    
def make_context_vector(context):
    return torch.tensor(context, dtype=torch.long).to(device)
```

and here is my forward function :

```
def forward(self, inputs):
        embeds = sum(self.embeddings(inputs)).view(1,-1)
        # print('embeds size: {}'.format(embeds.shape))
        out = self.linear1(embeds)
        out = self.activation_function1(out)
        # print('out1 size: {}'.format(out.shape))
        out = self.linear2(out)
        out = self.activation_function2(out)
        return out

#TRAINING
for epoch in range(50):
    total_loss = 0
    for context, target in data:
        context_vector = make_context_vector(context)  
        log_probs = model(context_vector)
        total_loss += loss_function(log_probs, torch.tensor([target], device = device))
    #optimize at the end of each epoch
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    total_loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

Please anybody help!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oh, my friend support me I found that not only set GPU for input, but also need to set GPU for the model.
So that, in the training code, I change it to:

```
model = CBOW(vocab_size, embedding_dim)**.to(device)**
```

Then, it worked well